# jQuery cookie not defined emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm very new to Ember and using Ember-CLI but I'm trying to set a private token for login using jQuery cookie, but it isn't defined. Please let me know if I'm doing the bower/broccoli stuff right. Most of the bower stuff was part of the scaffolded Ember-CLI app:

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "ember": "1.10.0",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.12",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.2.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.3.4",
    "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
    "jquery-cookie": "~1.4.1"
  }
}
```

Brocfile

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp();
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js');
app.import("bower_components/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js");

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

I've tried both (in Controller and Chrome console):

```
$.cookie()
```

and

```
Ember.$.cookie()
```

But for both I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Did you run bower install?

Comment: Yeah thats why my bower.json shows jquery cookie. Its there in the bower_components, just not loading into the DOM for some reason. :/

Comment: Did you restart the ember server?

Comment: Yes but then I updated ember-cli to 0.2.1 and now it's working...weird. Thanks for your help :)